# Easy way to print out whole datagridview

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

In VS 2012 C# WinForms applications, does anyone have an easy way to print out to a physical printer all of the rows to a DataGridView? I've tried Bitmaps but that only prints a screenshot basically and I've looked all over and couldn't find a simple version and all were out of date. A link to a good site or anything would be much appreciated.

Comment: you want to print, like in printer print?

Comment: @NoIdeaForName Yes, like printer print

Comment: Really unclear, what you mean by print? save to file? what format? Or Initiate a Printer to print?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Doing a quick google search led me to this article. It might be of some use for you. It's not "easy". You'll have to implement the functionality yourself. But it should get the results you want.

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/28046/Printing-of-DataGridView

Answer (score 1):

The easiest (and most expensive) way is to buy DevExpress Controls, or other 3rd party tools. -> [demo-export](http://demos.devexpress.com/aspxgridviewdemos/Exporting/Exporting.aspx)

The DevExpress Controls are much powerfull than standard controls, but this is expencive and commercial solution.

In the other way, developers time to find solution, develop and maintenance is also expensive.

Comment: Yeah, I'd rather not spend anything either.

Comment: Fast, cheap and easy; pick any two.

Answer (score 1):

I been using this since 2008, I cannot remember the source, but I fixed nearly all the issues of the original source code. Basically, it uses controls to generate the bitmap images.

Since it derives from `PrintDocument`, just add this component to your form, set the `DataGrid` property, and add a print button and use like any other `PrintDocument`.

```
Imports System.ComponentModel
Imports System.ComponentModel.Design
Imports System.Drawing.Printing

Namespace Windows.Forms

    <ToolboxBitmap(GetType(PrintDocument))> _
    Public Class DataGridViewPrintDocument
    Inherits PrintDocument

#Region " ColumnInfo "

    Private NotInheritable Class ColumnInfo
        Public ReadOnly Left As Integer
        Public ReadOnly Width As Integer
        Public ReadOnly Type As Type
        Public ReadOnly DisplayIndex As Integer
        Public ReadOnly HeaderText As String
        Public ReadOnly InheritedStyle As DataGridViewCellStyle
        Public ReadOnly ColumnName As String
        Public Sub New(ByVal left As Integer, ByVal width As Integer, ByVal column As DataGridViewColumn)
        Me.Left = left
        Me.Width = width
        Me.Type = column.GetType
        Me.DisplayIndex = column.DisplayIndex
        Me.HeaderText = column.HeaderText
        Me.InheritedStyle = column.InheritedStyle
        Me.ColumnName = column.Name
        End Sub
    End Class

#End Region

#Region " Sections "

    'DESIGN - add adornments property then print adornments
    '   this can take care of header, footer, watermark, and anything else
    '   adornments can be a base class with derived
    '       page info adornment
    '       date adornment
    '       document title adornment
    '       image adornment
    '       and so on
    '
    '   as currently implemented, adornments are for header and footer sections
    '   so, i changed the adornment class to the section class
    '

    Private NotInheritable Class Section
        Implements IDisposable

#Region " IDisposable Implementation "

        Private _disposed As Boolean

        Private Sub Dispose(ByVal disposing As Boolean)
        If Not _disposed Then
            If disposing Then
            _stringFormat.Dispose()
            _font.Dispose()
            End If
            _stringFormat = Nothing
            _font = Nothing
            _text = Nothing
            _disposed = True
        End If
        End Sub

        Public Sub Dispose() Implements IDisposable.Dispose
        Dispose(True)
        GC.SuppressFinalize(Me)
        End Sub
#End Region

        Private _text As String
        Private _bounds As Rectangle
        Private _font As Font
        Private _stringFormat As StringFormat

        Public Sub New(ByVal type As SectionType, ByVal text As String, ByVal font As Font, ByVal bounds As Rectangle, ByVal rtl As RightToLeft)
        _text = text
        _font = DirectCast(font.Clone, System.Drawing.Font)
        _bounds = bounds
        Dim iAlignment As DataGridViewContentAlignment = CType([Enum].Parse(GetType(DataGridViewContentAlignment), type.ToString), DataGridViewContentAlignment)
        _stringFormat = GatherStringFormat(iAlignment, DataGridViewTriState.False, rtl)
        End Sub

        Public Property Text() As String
        Get
            Return _text
        End Get
        Set(ByVal value As String)
            _text = value
        End Set
        End Property

        Public ReadOnly Property Bounds() As Rectangle
        Get
            Return _bounds
        End Get
        End Property

        Public ReadOnly Property font() As Font
        Get
            Return _font
        End Get
        End Property

        Public ReadOnly Property StringFormat() As StringFormat
        Get
            Return _stringFormat
        End Get
        End Property

    End Class

    Private Enum SectionType
        TopLeft
        TopCenter
        TopRight
        BottomLeft
        BottomCenter
        BottomRight
    End Enum

#End Region

#Region " IDisposable Implementation "

    Private _disposed As Boolean

    Private Sub PerformDispose(ByVal o As IDisposable)
        If o IsNot Nothing Then
        o.Dispose()
        End If
    End Sub

    Protected Overrides Sub Dispose(ByVal disposing As Boolean)

        Try
        If Not _disposed Then

            If disposing Then

            PerformDispose(_button)
            PerformDispose(_checkbox)
            PerformDispose(_picture)
            PerformDispose(_panel)

            If _cachedFormats IsNot Nothing Then
                For Each oPageInfo As Section In _cachedFormats.Values
                oPageInfo.Dispose()
                Next
            End If

            End If

            If _columns IsNot Nothing Then
            _columns.Clear()
            End If
            _columns = Nothing

            If _cachedFormats IsNot Nothing Then
            _cachedFormats.Clear()
            End If
            _cachedFormats = Nothing

            _button = Nothing
            _checkbox = Nothing
            _picture = Nothing
            _panel = Nothing
            _dataGrid = Nothing

            _disposed = True

        End If

        Finally
        MyBase.Dispose(disposing)

        End Try

    End Sub

#End Region

    Private _panel As Panel
    Private _button As Button
    Private _checkbox As CheckBox
    Private _picture As New PictureBox

    Private _columns As List(Of ColumnInfo)
    Private _cachedFormats As Dictionary(Of SectionType, Section)

    Private _rowPrintingIndex As Integer
    Private _rowCount As Integer

    Private _newPage As Boolean
    Private _pageNo As Integer

    Private _isPageCounting As Boolean
    Private _pageCount As Integer

    Private _dataGrid As DataGridView

    Private _totalColumnsWidth As Integer

    Public Sub New()
        Me.New(Nothing, False)
    End Sub

    Private Sub New(ByVal dataGrid As DataGridView, ByVal isPageCounting As Boolean)

        MyBase.New()

        _isPageCounting = isPageCounting
        _dataGrid = dataGrid

        If Not Me.IsPageCounting Then

        'using controls instead of the renderer classes
        'this allows for painting with the correct background and transparency colors

        _button = New Button
        _checkbox = New CheckBox
        _picture = New PictureBox

        'force creation of control handles
        '   this allows drawing transparent backgrounds
        '   and eliminates the black borders when using 'draw to bitmap'
        '   note, the check box does not need a parent control

        _panel = New Panel
        _panel.BackColor = SystemColors.Window
        _panel.Controls.AddRange(New Control() {_button, _picture})
        _panel.CreateControl()

        End If

    End Sub

    <DefaultValue(CType(Nothing, String))> _
    Public Property DataGrid() As DataGridView
        Get
        Return _dataGrid
        End Get
        Set(ByVal value As DataGridView)
        _dataGrid = value
        End Set
    End Property

    <Browsable(False)> _
    <DesignerSerializationVisibility(DesignerSerializationVisibility.Hidden)> _
    Public Property IsPageCounting() As Boolean
        Get
        Return _isPageCounting
        End Get
        Set(ByVal value As Boolean)
        _isPageCounting = value
        End Set
    End Property

    Private Sub InitializeSections()

        '   document name in top left corner
        '   date in bottom left corner
        '   pages in bottom right corner

        Dim oBounds As Rectangle
        Dim oMarginBounds As Rectangle = GatherDefaultMarginBounds(Me.DefaultPageSettings)

        _cachedFormats = New Dictionary(Of SectionType, Section)

        'hard-coded to half inch from edge until there is support for header margin
        oBounds = Rectangle.FromLTRB(oMarginBounds.Left, Me.DefaultPageSettings.Bounds.Top + 50, oMarginBounds.Right, Me.DefaultPageSettings.Bounds.Top + 100)

        _cachedFormats.Add(SectionType.TopLeft, New Section(SectionType.TopLeft, Me.DocumentName, New Font(Me.DataGrid.Font, FontStyle.Bold Or FontStyle.Italic), oBounds, Me.DataGrid.RightToLeft))

        'hard-coded to half inch from edge until there is support for header margin
        oBounds = Rectangle.FromLTRB(oMarginBounds.Left, Me.DefaultPageSettings.Bounds.Bottom - 100, oMarginBounds.Right, Me.DefaultPageSettings.Bounds.Bottom - 50)

        Dim sDate As String = String.Format("{0}", Now.ToLongDateString)

        _cachedFormats.Add(SectionType.BottomLeft, New Section(SectionType.BottomLeft, sDate, Me.DataGrid.Font, oBounds, Me.DataGrid.RightToLeft))
        _cachedFormats.Add(SectionType.BottomRight, New Section(SectionType.BottomRight, Nothing, Me.DataGrid.Font, oBounds, Me.DataGrid.RightToLeft))

    End Sub

    Protected Overrides Sub OnBeginPrint(ByVal e As System.Drawing.Printing.PrintEventArgs)

        If Me.DataGrid Is Nothing Then
        'nothing to do
        e.Cancel = True
        Exit Sub
        End If

        _columns = New List(Of ColumnInfo)

        _rowPrintingIndex = 0
        _newPage = True
        _pageNo = 1

        _rowCount = Me.DataGrid.RowCount

        Dim oMarginBounds As Rectangle = GatherDefaultMarginBounds(Me.DefaultPageSettings)
        Dim nLeft As Integer = oMarginBounds.Left
        Dim nWidth As Integer

        If Not Me.IsPageCounting Then

        InitializeSections()

        Using g As Graphics = Me.PrinterSettings.CreateMeasurementGraphics

            _totalColumnsWidth = Me.DataGrid.Columns.GetColumnsWidth(DataGridViewElementStates.Visible)

            Dim oColumn As DataGridViewColumn = Me.DataGrid.Columns.GetFirstColumn(DataGridViewElementStates.Visible)

            Do Until oColumn Is Nothing

            nWidth = CInt(System.Math.Floor(oMarginBounds.Width * oColumn.Width / _totalColumnsWidth))

            _columns.Add(New ColumnInfo(nLeft, nWidth, oColumn))

            nLeft += nWidth

            oColumn = Me.DataGrid.Columns.GetNextColumn(oColumn, DataGridViewElementStates.Visible, DataGridViewElementStates.None)

            Loop

        End Using

        End If

        MyBase.OnBeginPrint(e)

    End Sub

    Protected Overrides Sub OnPrintPage(ByVal e As System.Drawing.Printing.PrintPageEventArgs)

        Dim iRowTop As Integer = e.MarginBounds.Top + Me.DataGrid.ColumnHeadersHeight

        Do
        Dim oRow As DataGridViewRow = Me.DataGrid.Rows(_rowPrintingIndex)

        If oRow.IsNewRow Then
            Exit Do
        End If

        If iRowTop + oRow.Height >= e.MarginBounds.Bottom Then

            'we get here when printing all pages, except the last page
            e.HasMorePages = True
            If Not Me.IsPageCounting Then
            OnPaintPageFooter(e)
            End If
            _newPage = True
            _pageNo += 1
            MyBase.OnPrintPage(e)

            Exit Sub

        Else

            If Not Me.IsPageCounting Then

            If _newPage Then
                OnPaintPageHeader(e)
                OnPaintColumnHeaders(e)
                _newPage = False
            End If

            For Each oColInfo As ColumnInfo In _columns

                Dim oCellFace As Rectangle
                Dim oPaintEventArgs As DataGridViewPrintDocumentPaintEventArgs

                Dim oCell As DataGridViewCell = oRow.Cells(oColInfo.ColumnName)

                Debug.Assert(oCell IsNot Nothing, "Fix iT! We must find the cell!")

                'cell bounds, including border created by the grid lines
                oCellFace = New Rectangle( _
                oColInfo.Left, _
                iRowTop, _
                oColInfo.Width, _
                oRow.Height)

                'paint cell grid lines
                oPaintEventArgs = New DataGridViewPrintDocumentPaintEventArgs(e.Graphics, oCellFace, oCell)
                OnPaintCellBorder(oPaintEventArgs)

                'cell bounds, excluding cell grid lines
                oCellFace.Inflate(-1, -1)

                If oColInfo.Type Is GetType(DataGridViewTextBoxColumn) Then
                OnPaintTextBoxCell(oPaintEventArgs)
                ElseIf oColInfo.Type Is GetType(DataGridViewLinkColumn) Then
                OnPaintLinkCell(oPaintEventArgs)
                ElseIf oColInfo.Type Is GetType(DataGridViewComboBoxColumn) Then
                OnPaintComboBoxCell(oPaintEventArgs)
                ElseIf oColInfo.Type Is GetType(DataGridViewButtonColumn) Then
                OnPaintButtonCell(oPaintEventArgs)
                ElseIf oColInfo.Type Is GetType(DataGridViewCheckBoxColumn) Then
                OnPaintCheckBoxCell(oPaintEventArgs)
                ElseIf oColInfo.Type Is GetType(DataGridViewImageColumn) Then
                OnPaintImageCell(oPaintEventArgs)
                Else
                OnPaintCustomCell(oPaintEventArgs)
                End If

            Next

            End If

        End If

        iRowTop += oRow.Height
        _rowPrintingIndex += 1

        Loop While (_rowPrintingIndex < _rowCount)

        'we get here on the last page
        If Not Me.IsPageCounting Then
        OnPaintPageFooter(e)
        End If
        MyBase.OnPrintPage(e)

    End Sub

    Protected Overrides Sub OnEndPrint(ByVal e As System.Drawing.Printing.PrintEventArgs)

        If _columns IsNot Nothing Then
        _columns.Clear()
        End If
        _columns = Nothing

        _picture.Image = Nothing

        If _cachedFormats IsNot Nothing Then
        For Each oPageInfo As Section In _cachedFormats.Values
            oPageInfo.Dispose()
        Next
        _cachedFormats.Clear()
        End If
        _cachedFormats = Nothing

        MyBase.OnEndPrint(e)

    End Sub

#Region " OnPaint... Implementations "

    Protected Overridable Sub OnPaintTextBoxCell(ByVal e As DataGridViewPrintDocumentPaintEventArgs)
        If Len(e.Cell.FormattedValue) > 0 Then
        Dim oBounds As Rectangle = GatherContentBounds(e.ClipRectangle, e.Cell.InheritedStyle.Padding)
        Using oBrush As New SolidBrush(e.Cell.InheritedStyle.ForeColor)
            Using oStringFormat As StringFormat = GatherStringFormat(e.Cell.InheritedStyle.Alignment, e.Cell.InheritedStyle.WrapMode, Me.DataGrid.RightToLeft)
            e.Graphics.DrawString(CStr(e.Cell.FormattedValue), e.Cell.InheritedStyle.Font, oBrush, oBounds, oStringFormat)
            End Using
        End Using
        End If
    End Sub

    Protected Overridable Sub OnPaintLinkCell(ByVal e As DataGridViewPrintDocumentPaintEventArgs)
        Dim oLinkCell As DataGridViewLinkCell = DirectCast(e.Cell, DataGridViewLinkCell)
        If Len(e.Cell.FormattedValue) > 0 Then
        Dim oBounds As Rectangle = GatherContentBounds(e.ClipRectangle, e.Cell.InheritedStyle.Padding)
        Dim oLinkColor As Color = DirectCast(IIf(oLinkCell.LinkVisited, oLinkCell.VisitedLinkColor, oLinkCell.LinkColor), Color)
        Using oBrush As New SolidBrush(oLinkColor)
            Using oFont As New Font(e.Cell.InheritedStyle.Font, FontStyle.Underline)
            Using oStringFormat As StringFormat = GatherStringFormat(e.Cell.InheritedStyle.Alignment, e.Cell.InheritedStyle.WrapMode, Me.DataGrid.RightToLeft)
                e.Graphics.DrawString(CStr(e.Cell.FormattedValue), oFont, oBrush, oBounds, oStringFormat)
            End Using
            End Using
        End Using
        End If
    End Sub

    Protected Overridable Sub OnPaintComboBoxCell(ByVal e As DataGridViewPrintDocumentPaintEventArgs)
        OnPaintTextBoxCell(e)
    End Sub

    Protected Overridable Sub OnPaintButtonCell(ByVal e As DataGridViewPrintDocumentPaintEventArgs)
        If Len(e.Cell.FormattedValue) > 0 Then
        Dim oBounds As Rectangle = GatherContentBounds(e.ClipRectangle, e.Cell.InheritedStyle.Padding)
        Dim oFace As New Rectangle(oBounds.X + 1, oBounds.Y + 1, oBounds.Width - 2, oBounds.Height - 3)
        _button.Size = oFace.Size
        _button.Text = CStr(e.Cell.FormattedValue)
        Using oBitmap As New Bitmap(oFace.Width, oFace.Height)
            _button.DrawToBitmap(oBitmap, New Rectangle(0, 0, oFace.Width, oFace.Height))
            e.Graphics.DrawImageUnscaled(oBitmap, oFace)
        End Using
        End If
    End Sub

    Protected Overridable Sub OnPaintCheckBoxCell(ByVal e As DataGridViewPrintDocumentPaintEventArgs)

        _checkbox.Checked = CBool(e.Cell.FormattedValue)

        Dim iCheckBoxState As VisualStyles.CheckBoxState

        If _checkbox.Checked Then
        iCheckBoxState = VisualStyles.CheckBoxState.UncheckedNormal
        Else
        iCheckBoxState = VisualStyles.CheckBoxState.UncheckedNormal
        End If

        Using oControlGraphics As Graphics = _checkbox.CreateGraphics
        _checkbox.Size = CheckBoxRenderer.GetGlyphSize(oControlGraphics, iCheckBoxState)
        End Using

        Dim oBounds As Rectangle = GatherContentBounds(e.ClipRectangle, e.Cell.InheritedStyle.Padding)

        Dim oBoundsCenteredOnCellFace As New Rectangle( _
         oBounds.Left + ((oBounds.Width - _checkbox.Size.Width) \ 2), _
         oBounds.Top + ((oBounds.Height - _checkbox.Size.Height) \ 2), _
         _checkbox.Width, _
         _checkbox.Height)

        Using oBitmap As New Bitmap(_checkbox.Width + 1, _checkbox.Height + 1)
        _checkbox.DrawToBitmap(oBitmap, New Rectangle(1, 1, _checkbox.Width, _checkbox.Height))
        e.Graphics.DrawImageUnscaled(oBitmap, oBoundsCenteredOnCellFace)
        End Using

    End Sub

    Protected Overridable Sub OnPaintImageCell(ByVal e As DataGridViewPrintDocumentPaintEventArgs)

        Dim oImageCell As DataGridViewImageCell = DirectCast(e.Cell, DataGridViewImageCell)
        Dim oImage As Image = DirectCast(oImageCell.FormattedValue, Image)

        Dim oBounds As Rectangle = GatherContentBounds(e.ClipRectangle, e.Cell.InheritedStyle.Padding)

        Dim oFace As New Rectangle( _
        oBounds.X + 1, _
        oBounds.Y + 1, _
        oBounds.Width - 2, _
        oBounds.Height - 4)

        _picture.Size = oFace.Size

        Select Case oImageCell.ImageLayout

        Case DataGridViewImageCellLayout.Stretch
            _picture.SizeMode = PictureBoxSizeMode.StretchImage

        Case DataGridViewImageCellLayout.Normal
            _picture.SizeMode = PictureBoxSizeMode.CenterImage

        Case DataGridViewImageCellLayout.Zoom
            _picture.SizeMode = PictureBoxSizeMode.Zoom

        Case Else
            Debug.Fail("FixiT! We must support all possible image layout values.")
        End Select

        _picture.Image = oImage

        Using oBitmap As New Bitmap(oFace.Width, oFace.Height)
        _picture.DrawToBitmap(oBitmap, New Rectangle(0, 0, oFace.Width, oFace.Height))
        e.Graphics.DrawImageUnscaled(oBitmap, oFace)
        End Using

        _picture.Image = Nothing

    End Sub

    Protected Overridable Sub OnPaintCustomCell(ByVal e As DataGridViewPrintDocumentPaintEventArgs)
        OnPaintTextBoxCell(e)
    End Sub

    Protected Overridable Sub OnPaintCellBorder(ByVal e As DataGridViewPrintDocumentPaintEventArgs)
        Using oPen As New Pen(Me.DataGrid.GridColor)
        e.Graphics.DrawRectangle(oPen, e.ClipRectangle)
        End Using
    End Sub

    Protected Overridable Sub OnPaintPageHeader(ByVal e As System.Drawing.Printing.PrintPageEventArgs)

        'left section
        If _cachedFormats.ContainsKey(SectionType.TopLeft) Then
        PaintSection(e.Graphics, _cachedFormats.Item(SectionType.TopLeft))
        End If

        'center section
        If _cachedFormats.ContainsKey(SectionType.TopCenter) Then
        PaintSection(e.Graphics, _cachedFormats.Item(SectionType.TopCenter))
        End If

        'right section
        If _cachedFormats.ContainsKey(SectionType.TopRight) Then
        PaintSection(e.Graphics, _cachedFormats.Item(SectionType.TopRight))
        End If

    End Sub

    Protected Overridable Sub OnPaintColumnHeaders(ByVal e As System.Drawing.Printing.PrintPageEventArgs)

        For Each oColInfo As ColumnInfo In _columns

        Dim oColumn As DataGridViewColumn = Me.DataGrid.Columns.Item(oColInfo.ColumnName)

        'header cell bounds, including border created by the grid lines
        Dim oCellFace As Rectangle = New Rectangle(oColInfo.Left, e.MarginBounds.Top, oColInfo.Width, Me.DataGrid.ColumnHeadersHeight)

        e.Graphics.FillRectangle(SystemBrushes.Control, oCellFace)

        Using oPen As New Pen(oColInfo.InheritedStyle.ForeColor)
            e.Graphics.DrawRectangle(oPen, oCellFace)
            Using oStringFormat As StringFormat = GatherStringFormat(oColumn.InheritedStyle.Alignment, DataGridViewTriState.False, Me.DataGrid.RightToLeft)
            e.Graphics.DrawString(oColInfo.HeaderText, oColInfo.InheritedStyle.Font, oPen.Brush, oCellFace, oStringFormat)
            End Using
        End Using

        Next

    End Sub

    Protected Overridable Sub OnPaintPageFooter(ByVal e As System.Drawing.Printing.PrintPageEventArgs)

        'left section
        If _cachedFormats.ContainsKey(SectionType.BottomLeft) Then
        PaintSection(e.Graphics, _cachedFormats.Item(SectionType.BottomLeft))
        End If

        'center section
        If _cachedFormats.ContainsKey(SectionType.BottomCenter) Then
        PaintSection(e.Graphics, _cachedFormats.Item(SectionType.BottomCenter))
        End If

        'right section
        If _cachedFormats.ContainsKey(SectionType.BottomRight) Then
        Dim oSection As Section = _cachedFormats.Item(SectionType.BottomRight)
        oSection.Text = String.Format("{0} of {1}", _pageNo, _pageCount)
        PaintSection(e.Graphics, oSection)
        End If

    End Sub

#End Region

    Private Shared Sub PaintSection(ByVal g As Graphics, ByVal section As Section)
        g.DrawString(section.Text, section.font, SystemBrushes.WindowText, section.Bounds, section.StringFormat)
    End Sub

    Private Shared Function GatherStringFormat(ByVal alignment As DataGridViewContentAlignment, ByVal wrapMode As DataGridViewTriState, ByVal rtl As RightToLeft) As StringFormat
        Dim oResult As StringFormat = Tools.CreateStringFormat(CType(alignment, ContentAlignment), True, False, rtl, False, False)
        If wrapMode = DataGridViewTriState.True Then
        oResult.FormatFlags = oResult.FormatFlags Or StringFormatFlags.NoWrap
        End If
        Return oResult
    End Function

    ''' <summary>
    ''' Deflates a rectangle by the specified padding.
    ''' </summary>
    Private Shared Function GatherContentBounds(ByVal rect As Rectangle, ByVal padding As Padding) As Rectangle
        rect.X += padding.Left
        rect.Y += padding.Top
        rect.Width -= padding.Horizontal
        rect.Height -= padding.Vertical
        Return rect
    End Function

    Private Shared Function GatherDefaultMarginBounds(ByVal pageSettings As PageSettings) As Rectangle
        Dim oMargins As Margins = pageSettings.Margins
        Dim oPageBounds As Rectangle = pageSettings.Bounds
        Return Rectangle.FromLTRB(oMargins.Left, oMargins.Top, oPageBounds.Right - oMargins.Right, oPageBounds.Bottom - oMargins.Bottom)
    End Function

    End Class

    Public Class DataGridViewPrintDocumentPaintEventArgs
    Inherits PaintEventArgs
    Public ReadOnly Cell As DataGridViewCell
    Public Sub New(ByVal graphics As Graphics, ByVal clipRect As Rectangle, ByVal cell As DataGridViewCell)
        MyBase.New(graphics, clipRect)
        Me.Cell = cell
    End Sub
    End Class

End Namespace
```

Comment: Wow! This looks like `VB.NET`? The OP seems to be interested in `C#`

Comment: .NET is .NET, WinForms is WinForms. Doesn't make a difference, poster can convert the code easily enough at <http://www.developerfusion.com/tools/convert/csharp-to-vb/> or any of the other converters.

Comment: @Stick; Don't get stuck on any bias between the languages. In a current solution I have, there are 19 C# projects and 5 VB.NET projects. Each languages has their strengths and weaknesses.

Answer (score 0):

There is no easy way to just put a print button on the `DataGridView` and have it print all the pages of the grid view, because the `DataGridView` does not have an export capability built into it.

You have these options:

- Export the data to another tool (i.e. Microsoft Excel) and then print from there. To see how to do this read [How to export from DatagridView to Excel Sheet in C# Windows Forms](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/windows/en-US/8cc50b45-bd55-4280-a8e7-28baeaa5cdcb/how-to-export-from-datagridview-to-excel-sheet-in-c-windows-forms).
- Use the `ReportViewer` control that has exporting capabilities built-in and then print the resulting exported data. To see how to do this read [Using the WinForms ReportViewer Control](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa337089.aspx)

Comment: I'd rather just have a print button than export data to another tool, just to make it more user friendly

Comment: Well then it sounds like you are going to have to buy something beyond what is currently in your Visual Studio toolbox, according to zchpit the DevExpress controls might do the trick.